# INCLUDE function works but does not refer to CSS

Tags: php, include, relative-path, phpbb3

I am working on restyling a phpbb board. Even if there is a support forum on the phpbb platform, I would like to ask for your kind help.

I managed to include a `footer.php` file into `overall_footer.html`.
The paths are:

```
WEBSITE/forum/styles/stylename/template/overall_footer.html
WEBSITE/footer.php
```

the function:
`<!-- INCLUDEPHP /../../../../footer.php -->`

The problem is that, while in other pages `footer.php` correctly refers to the stylesheet located in

```
WEBSITE/stylesheet.css
```

once included in the board it does not refer to it at all...
If I add the traditional `<link href="...." rel="stylesheet"` to `footer.php`, the stylesheet then applies to the whole board (that should have css defined by the chosen theme).
What is the obvious thing that I just can't see?
Any help is truly appreciated!
Mya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off referencing your assets relative to a known point on your site.

There are several techniques for this... like:

Use the document root as your starting point

```
include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/myfunctions.php");
```

or set up a constant

```
define("APP_ROOT", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
```

or even in a .htaccess file

```
SetEnv APP_ROOT "/path/to/myroot";
```

For URL based includes (js /css/ hrefs)

Always use absolute paths when referring to assets on your site (beginning with a /)
except for images and fonts loaded from within a css file, those can be loaded relative to the css file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am new in all of this so now my questions are about basics: where should I put the `include ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/myfunctions.php");`? Just before `<!-- INCLUDEPHP /../footer.php -->` (which, btw, I hope would be the correct absolute path in this case)? thanks for you patience

Comment: It all depends on where your footer.php is relative to the document root. if you have to go down into an themes directory then a bobstheme directory  includes directory to find it you would do `include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/themes/bobstheme/footer.php");`

Comment: Got it. But the footer.php is above the document root (i.e. the root of the file I am writing in, right?). Therefore the complete paths are : `www/footer.php` and `www/forum/styles/stylename/template/overall_footer.html` (the latter the document where I put the INCLUDE.